# Randomly missing ESI content on tablet and mobile devices using Symfony2 and varnish

Tags: mobile, symfony, tablet, varnish, esi

I have a weird issue where some content included via Edge Side Include is randomly missing. Its a menu wrapped in a header tag. Sometimes it displays in the browser sometimes its missing.

A few notes:

1) This only happens on mobile and tablet devices. I have been able to reproduce the error on an ipad, blackberry torch and an android phone (Samsung galaxy s3) using the default android browser, firefox and chrome for android.

2) I installed the Android SDK for debugging but received no errors. The only thing I found was everytime the header was missing there were also no cookies set which is odd. And then when the header was displayed there were cookies set.

3) The problem can be rectified by clearing all web data in the browser (cookies, cache etc).

The application is written in Symfony2.1
The reverse proxy server is Varnish

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like a varnish issue. have you tried using symfony's internal proxy without varnish?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. What exactly do you mean by "symfony's internal proxy" please?

Comment: Please see: http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/new-symfony-2.2/fragments-esi-caching. Use the internal routing for symfony 2.1 and disable esi/varnish temporarily. check your symfony & php logs aswell for exceptions.

Comment: I sincerely doubt this is a varnish issue. Varnish does not care about the User-Agent of the client unless you explicitly program it to in VCL.